# No classifiers in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I just found out about weka so I decided to try it out. I downloaded some training data:

```
@relation weather

@attribute outlook {sunny, overcast, rainy}
@attribute temperature real
@attribute humidity real
@attribute windy {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute play {yes, no}

@data
sunny,85,85,FALSE,no
sunny,80,90,TRUE,no
overcast,83,86,FALSE,yes
rainy,70,96,FALSE,yes
rainy,68,80,FALSE,yes
rainy,65,70,TRUE,no
overcast,64,65,TRUE,yes
sunny,72,95,FALSE,no
sunny,69,70,FALSE,yes
rainy,75,80,FALSE,yes
sunny,75,70,TRUE,yes
overcast,72,90,TRUE,yes
overcast,81,75,FALSE,yes
rainy,71,91,TRUE,no
```

When I go to the classify tab in weka and click "choose", it does not have any classifiers and the "choose" dialog is just empty. Do I have to download anything in addition to Weka?

Comment: In Weka you can download various classifiers and other modules using the Package Manager (Tools -> Package Manager), but quite a few classifiers are already included. Can you tell us exactly which version of Weka you are using, what OS and what exactly you did that resulted in an empty "choose" dialog?

Comment: I am using Version 3.8.0. My OS: Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit. I just opened the .arff file in the Weka Explorer, then went to Classify and presses the "choose" button.

Comment: Oh and also i just installed a classifier called AnDE, but the "choose" dialog is still empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No classifiers in Weka Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302781/no-classifiers-in-weka-explorer)