# No classifiers in Weka Explorer

Tags: weka

I just found out about weka so I decided to try it out. I downloaded some training data:

```
@relation weather

@attribute outlook {sunny, overcast, rainy}
@attribute temperature real
@attribute humidity real
@attribute windy {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute play {yes, no}

@data
sunny,85,85,FALSE,no
sunny,80,90,TRUE,no
overcast,83,86,FALSE,yes
rainy,70,96,FALSE,yes
rainy,68,80,FALSE,yes
rainy,65,70,TRUE,no
overcast,64,65,TRUE,yes
sunny,72,95,FALSE,no
sunny,69,70,FALSE,yes
rainy,75,80,FALSE,yes
sunny,75,70,TRUE,yes
overcast,72,90,TRUE,yes
overcast,81,75,FALSE,yes
rainy,71,91,TRUE,no
```

When I go to the classify tab in weka and click "choose", it does not have any classifiers and the "choose" dialog is just empty. Do I have to download anything in addition to Weka? I am using Weka 3.8.0

By the way: I already asked that question but i got no answer from it.

Comment: I am also using Weka 3.8.0. I copied your data into an arff file loaded it and saw lots of classifier options in the classifier "Choose" dialog.   When you were in the "Preprocess"  tab  did you see 5 attributes?  Is the data loading correctly?  If so,  it might be worth trying to uninstall WEKA and reinstall.

Comment: Yes i do see 5 attributes. How can i see if the data is loaded correctly? For me it seems ok it shows the attributs and all the labels and count are correct.

Comment: If you see the 5 attributes,  it is probably loaded correctly. Do the other tabs work?  For example, if you click the Visualize tab,  do you see the scatterplots?

Comment: Thank you very much the reinstall did it. I think it was because when i tried reinstalling the first time, i did not install in the default directory. Thanks again!

Comment: Great!    Have fun.

Comment: I have a similar sounding issue when using two screens. On my primary monitor the GUI works fine, on the secondary monitor the dialogue boxes get mangled.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by reinstalling weka in the default  path.

EDIT:
    This is the solution that works for me 100%:

> I have a similar sounding issue when using two screens. On my primary
>   monitor the GUI works fine, on the secondary monitor the dialogue
>   boxes get mangled. – S van Balen Dec 29 '16 at 12:31